Why is the "invisible" field null in GetStream.io dashboard despite setting it to false when querying users?
I'm encountering an issue with GetStream.io while querying users. Despite explicitly setting the "invisible" field to false in the user object during the query, the field remains null in the GetStream.io dashboard. Here's the relevant code and error message:
`Failure(value=NetworkError(message=Response is failed. See cause, serverErrorCode=1000, statusCode=-1, cause=com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected BOOLEAN but was null at path $.invisible at $.users[1]))

val user = User(
  id = id,
  name = name,
  image = photo,
  invisible = false

)`
user details in getstream dashboard
